# auto fill an ID in the form in access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to create an ID in a Form for a DB in access where the ID is automatically generated by the date.time.user ID  like / 161212.2227.s978904/

I create it in VBA excel but not working in access.

```
Sub IDgen()

Dim ID, Yr, Dt, Mth, Hr, Min As Integer


ID = Environ("username")
Yr = Right(Year(Date), 2)
Mth = Format(Month(Date), "#00")
Dt = Format(Day(Date), "#00")
Hr = Format(Hour(Time), "#00")
Min = Format(Minute(Time), "#00")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = "C" & Yr & Mth & Dt & "." & Hr & Min & "." & ID

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a function that returns the ID and call that from your form:

```
Function GetId() As String
    Dim ID As String, Yr As String
    Dim Dt As String, Mth As String
    Dim Hr As String, Min As String

    ID = Environ("username")
    Yr = Right(Year(Date), 2)
    Mth = Format(Month(Date), "#00")
    Dt = Format(Day(Date), "#00")
    Hr = Format(Hour(Time), "#00")
    Min = Format(Minute(Time), "#00")

    GetId = "C" & Yr & Mth & Dt & "." & Hr & Min & "." & ID

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I did it like this.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Yr = Right(Year(Date), 2)
Mth = Format(Month(Date), "#00")
Dt = Format(Day(Date), "#00")
Hr = Format(Hour(Time), "#00")
Min = Format(Minute(Time), "#00")

Me.Text56.Value = "C" & Yr & Mth & Dt & "." & Hr & Min & "." & Environ("username")

End Sub
```